# sort select menu alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I've got the following select menu ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAYvL/2/)):

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Cars</option>
  <option value="saab">------------</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Using Javascript, how would I re-sort the list alphabetically, excluding the first 2 options (`Cars` and `-------`), which must remain at the top? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As far as displaying a heading in the <select> list, you should look into using HTML <optgroup> functionality.  That way, you could alphabetize all of the options and have the desired effect.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Answer (score 14):

Being a purist, I would say that at no point was jQuery specifically mentioned or asked for, it may not be in use in this project for one reason or another.  Here's an example using pure javascript.

```
function sortlist(){

 var cl = document.getElementById('carlist');
 var clTexts = new Array();

 for(i = 2; i < cl.length; i++){
    clTexts[i-2] =
        cl.options[i].text.toUpperCase() + "," +
        cl.options[i].text + "," +
        cl.options[i].value + "," +
        cl.options[i].selected;
 }

 clTexts.sort();

 for(i = 2; i < cl.length; i++){
    var parts = clTexts[i-2].split(',');

    cl.options[i].text = parts[1];
    cl.options[i].value = parts[2];
    if(parts[3] == "true"){
        cl.options[i].selected = true;
    }else{
       cl.options[i].selected = false;
    }
 }
}

sortlist();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GAYvL/7/

**Updated** to be case neutral.

Comment: I really like working with jQuery because it's so easy...which is also it's biggest downfall.  No reason to add extra overhead - I would vote for your answer.

Comment: jQuery is great, and I'd heavily advocate its usage ... but I'd feel guilty if someone had to add jQuery to a project just to support something like this ... thanks for the vote of confidence :)

Comment: This Put's upper case ahead of all lowercase leading to something like `ABCabc` rather than `AaBbCc`

Comment: I've made a slight modification to make it as close to case neutral as it's likely to need to be.

Comment: note that this will not retain the `selected` attribute to the correct option

Comment: This fails if the value of `<option>` has a comma in it.

Comment: I agree with you, 100%! So are we just pretending this is indeed case neutral...

Answer (score 2):

My first approach was similar to Koolinc's, using Array.prototype.slice to convert the `<select>` element's children NodeList to an array.  However, this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8 and lower so I changed it to extract, sort and then re-insert:

```
var sel = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0],
    opts = [];

// Extract the elements into an array
for (var i=sel.options.length-1; i >= 2; i--)
    opts.push(sel.removeChild(sel.options[i]));

// Sort them
opts.sort(function (a, b) { 
    return a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML);
});

// Put them back into the <select>
while(opts.length)
    sel.appendChild(opts.shift());
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3YjNR/2/**

Answer (score 2):

This is just a more generic answser based on @Jeff Parker's one!

```
function sortSelect(select, startAt) {
    if(typeof startAt === 'undefined') {
        startAt = 0;
    }

    var texts = [];

    for(var i = startAt; i < select.length; i++) {
        texts[i] = [
            select.options[i].text.toUpperCase(),
            select.options[i].text,
            select.options[i].value
        ].join('|');
    }

    texts.sort();

    texts.forEach(function(text, index) {
        var parts = text.split('|');

        select.options[startAt + index].text = parts[1];
        select.options[startAt + index].value = parts[2];
    });
}
```

I have also created a fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/4u86B/1/

Comment: This fails if the value of `<option>` has a `|` in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by giving a class name to all of the entries I want to sort, and giving and ID to the select:

```
 <select id="sortableCars">
   <option value="volvo">Cars</option>
   <option class="sortMe" value="saab">------------</option>
   <option class="sortMe" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option class="sortMe" value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option class="sortMe" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option class="sortMe" value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

as for the javascript

```
 var mylist = $('#sortableCars');
 var listitems = mylist.children('option.sortMe').get();
 listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
 })
 $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

Comment: You will get a select with both the unordered options and the ordered options this way since you are using mylist.append().

Comment: Close, but the JS doesn't work quite right in my testing. Changing listitems to be `$('#sortableCars > .sortMe')` and removing the `sortMe` class from the '-------' option solves my problems.

Comment: I fixed it to select only those with the class 'sortMe'.  Funny how you can miss the important details...