# Search and get backup removed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, html-select, removechild

I have created a javascript search in select element.

option tag does not get any CSS to hide or display none, for this solution I have removed unmatched option and make a backup for removed option for reset list button.

It's working fine but I have a problem, I have about 19000 option for this select list.
search works fine but when I hit reset button, only 9500 option from 19000 comes back.

I appreciate your help.

Here is the code:

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/absalan/pen/nuhEg/)

HTML

```
<h1>Search in select "option" tag</h1>
<select multiple name="selectMenu" id="selectMenu" style="width:100px" size=10>
<option value ="item 1">item 1</option>
<option value ="item 2">item 2</option>
<option value ="thing 3">thing 3</option>
<option value ="item 4">item 4</option>
<option value ="stuff 5">stuff 5</option>
<option value ="stuff 6">stuff 6</option>
<option value ="stuff 7">stuff 7</option>
<option value ="item 8">item 8</option>
</select>

<p>Search within this list</p>
<input type=text name="search" id="search" onkeypress="searchItems();">
<br>
<input type=button value="Search" onclick="searchItems();">
<input type=button value="Reset List" onclick="resetList();">
```

Javascript

```
var itemList = null;
var itemListOriginal = new Array();
var backup = false;

function searchItems() {
    itemList = document.getElementById("selectMenu");
    var searchStrObj = document.getElementById("search");
    var itemDescription = "";

    // replace white space with wild card
    var searchString = searchStrObj.value;
    searchString = searchString.replace(" ", ".*");

    var re = new RegExp("(" + searchString + ")", "i"); //"i" sets "ignore case" flag

    if (itemListOriginal.length < 1)
        backup = true;
    else
        backup = false;

    // loop through options and check for matches
    for (i=itemList.options.length - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        itemDescription = itemList.options.item(i).text; 

        if (backup) {
            hash = new Array();
            hash['name'] = itemDescription;
            hash['value'] = itemList.options.item(i).value;
            itemListOriginal[i] = hash;
        }

        if (!itemDescription.match(re)) {
            itemList.remove(i);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function resetList() {
    //hack! remove all elements from list before repopulating
    for (i=itemList.options.length - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        itemList.remove(i);
    }

    for (i=0; i < itemListOriginal.length; i++) {
        hash = itemListOriginal[i];
        //option = new Option(hash['name'], hash['value']); REMOVED
        //itemList.options.add(option, i); REMOVED
        itemList.options[i] = new Option(hash['name'], hash['value'], false, false);
    }

    document.getElementById("search").value = "";
}
```

Comment: From next time, please include your code here on SO, rather than attaching a link.

Comment: Sorry it was long code and it was hard to add here because some of code was hiding.

Comment: Yes, please!  I've added it for you since I was editing something else.

Comment: Wow it was nice, thanks man.

Comment: Why not simply hide/show options?

Comment: @David.titan is using jQuery lib ok for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[## `DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/9U445/2/)

---

I've observed that in your code backup is changed every time you call the function `searchitems()`.

Thus erasing the old values that were stored in it.

So I've changed that

```
It is working fine but I have a problem, 
I have about 19000 option for this select list. 
search works fine but when I hit reset button, 
only 9500 option from 19000 comes back.
```

That is the reason behind that. So I've modified your code and added a global variable `backupList` in that.
so when the unwanted elements are removed old elements aren't deleted in my code but instead, new removed elements are appended to old removed elements using `+=` shorthand operator.

also rather creating `options` dynamically and using `.add` or `.append` or any similar `javascript` method I'm using  `.innerHTML` for simplicity as you can see in the code. only problem is that now after you click `reset` elements will not be sorted as it was in the first case, You'll need to sort them believe me it is easy. for sorting refer: [sort select menu alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248189/sort-select-menu-alphabetically).

```
var itemList = null;
var itemListOriginal = new Array();
var backup = false;
var backupList =""; // To store removed elements

function searchItems() {
itemList = document.getElementById("selectMenu");
var searchStrObj = document.getElementById("search");
var itemDescription = "";
var searchString = searchStrObj.value;
searchString = searchString.replace(" ", ".*");
var re = new RegExp("(" + searchString + ")", "i"); //"i" sets "ignore case" flag
for (i=itemList.options.length - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        itemDescription = itemList.options.item(i).text; 
        var hash = new Array();
        hash['name'] = itemDescription;
        hash['value'] = itemList.options.item(i).value;
        itemListOriginal[i] = hash;
        if (!itemDescription.match(re)) {
          itemList.remove(i); //Remove Unwanted Elements
          backupList+="<option value='"+ hash['value']+"'>"+itemDescription+"</option>"; 
         /* append new unwanted elements with previous, 
           initially it is blank "". 
           This is Important 
         */
        }
}
return false;
}

function resetList() {
var itemList = document.getElementById("selectMenu");
itemList.innerHTML+=backupList; /* Add removed elements to list. 
alternate to .append,.add or similar function*/
backupList=""; // Make Backup Empty!
document.getElementById("search").value = "";
}
```

Hope it helps! cheers :)!

Comment: Not that much :). I'm glad that i could help you. and yeah your coding style reminds me of myself in early days. +1 for asking such a question.

Comment: It was great answer with nice details, thanks again.