# Sorting a dropdown list with javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown list, but the options are not set in the correct order. Is there a way to sort them (based on their value i guess) using javascript?

```
<select class="required" name="payment_gateway">
<option value="bank-transfer">Bank</option>
<option value="pay-social">Social</option>
<option value="paypal">PayPal</option>
<option value="pronamic_ideal">iDEAL</option>
</select>
```

The desired sorting would be:

```
<select class="required" name="payment_gateway">
<option value="pay-social">Social</option>
<option value="pronamic_ideal">iDEAL</option>
<option value="bank-transfer">Bank</option>
<option value="paypal">PayPal</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend jQuery, if you can't, take a look in the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667010/sorting-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [sort select menu alphabetically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248189/sort-select-menu-alphabetically)

Comment: actually i would like the 'pay-social' to be the first option.

Comment: on what condition would you like to order the list? custom or for instance alphabetically?

Comment: There isn't enough information to help here. How are you currently outputting the select options? It's not clear that you couldn't just re-order your HTML.

Comment: The desired order is given. The list is now populated through php and it would require editing the core files in order to change the sorting. Thats why i was hoping that sorting through javascript/jquery would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write so

```
var $dropdown = $('.required'),
    $items = $dropdown.children('option');


$items.sort(function(a, b){
    var an = a.value,
        bn = b.value;
    if (an > bn) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (an < bn) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
$items.detach().appendTo($dropdown);
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for your response. This is not changing the order however. Everything stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working, however the wrong option is still selected.

```
$('.required option[value="pay-social"]').insertBefore('.required option[value="bank-transfer"]');
```

Comment: This can be fixed by:   $("form.formcustsort .required").prop("selectedIndex", 0);

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example

```
<select class="required" name="payment_gateway"><option value="pay-social">Social</option><option value="pronamic_ideal">iDEAL</option><option value="bank-transfer">Bank</option><option value="paypal">PayPal</option></select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/snayps/tdh9up7h/

Comment: thannks, but Im not sure what you mean. In the fiddle example the options are already sorted in html..